# removing all desktop environments installed and get a new one

Tags: desktop-environments

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and had gnome initially. I Tried Ubuntu studio. Now I don't like that either. How do I remove all the existing environments and get a new environment? And any suggestions for the  environments? Im looking for something with a good UI.

Comment: There's no good reliable way to uninstall a desktop environment because any one is made of multiple interacting parts. Better install the flavor you really want. Suggestions of environment you can get in forum. A Q&A is not the place because the answer you're looking for is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Segmentation_fault, here are some suggestions for the environments: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available .

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like this I would suggest a re-install. And next time use a container (a Ubuntu installed in virtualbox or vmware) to play with desktops and not the system to actually use. Removing a container is easy. Restoring an OS is also possible but artifacts (configuration files or settings) might remain. Less hassle to just re-install.

> And any suggestions for the environments? Im looking for something with a good UI.

You forgot to define what "good" means. Unity is excellent. So are KDE, XFCE and LXDE. To each their own ...